# Chrome: Google Cast Retrieve Available Device List

Tags: google-cast

I worked with the pre-release SDK before the official SDK was released. Before I could retrieve a list of devices and display them however I wanted. For example, [Google Music](http://music.google.com) still has this functionality.

[image: Google Music list]

With the official release, is there any other way, besides having the Chromecast Extension popup with the list, to show available devices? I've been searching the documentation for an answer with no results.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the functionality is now handled by the extension to make it more uniform across all apps that use this feature, and to avoid confusion as to what the cast icon is in the chrome itself on the top right and what is the cast icon inside the player. Now both provide the same functionality if you are within a cast-enabled app.